# Script error with gmlib 1.5.3 & 1.5.0 in C++ Builder XE2

Tags: gmlib

I used `Webbrowser`, `GMMap`, `GMMarker`, `GMPolyline` in my C++ project to show the route that I had walked through and the realtime position.

At the beginning,I had used the version of `1.5.0 GMlib` without any errors before. However, there were a lot of script errors when the project begin to execute.

As a result, I have tried the newest version `1.5.3 GMlib` in my C++ builder. And I had solved the problems temporarily. The next day, all the script errors problems come back again. So, it seems that this problem can not be solved by setup newest version of `GMlib`. Is there any other way to solve this problem ?

Thanks for the people who would like to help me solve the problem!

The script error is like the following picture：

[image]

Comment: seems that Google do some changes into the API. I'm working on that

Comment: Thanks for your reply. At the same time, I have searched some similar case in Delphi, the detail is in following URL： http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583783/tgmdirection-script-error/13594517#13594517
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26365774/google-maps-js-api-v3-infowindow-script-error-json-undefined